# Returning `nil` from a `compactMap()` closure fails result type check

Tags: swift, functional-programming

In this snippet, I try to map `[RegisteredMediaAttachment]` to `[BasicAttachmentInput]`, but only for those items that have a parseable `uploadUrl`.

```swift
    private func createSecondaryAttachments(
        _ attachments: [RegisteredMediaAttachment]
    ) -> [BasicAttachmentInput] {
        return attachments.compactMap {
            guard let name = URL(string: $0.registration.uploadUrl) else {
                return nil
            }

            return BasicAttachmentInput(
                name: name,
                contentType: $0.attachment.type.mime(),
                sizeBytes: $0.attachment.data.count,
                mediaId: $0.registration.media.id
            )
        }
    }
```

However, Swift complains on the line `return nil` that `'nil' is not compatible with closure result type 'BasicAttachmentInput'`

This surprises me. I expect the function to compile and reduce the map result to contain only non-`nil` values returned from the `compactMap` closure. What is wrong with the snippet above?

Comment: to achieve what you want, you could try this:
             `func createSecondaryAttachments(_ attachments: [RegisteredMediaAttachment]) -> [BasicAttachmentInput] {
                 return attachments.compactMap {
                     if let name = URL(string: $0.uploadUrl) {
                         return BasicAttachmentInput(.....)
                     }
                 }
             }`, but to fully explain your error is more difficult.

Comment: Is this one of those cases where Swift is not smart enough to infer the type again? Try writing all the types explicitly, `attachments.compactMap { (attachment: RegisteredMediaAttachment) -> BasicAttachmentInput?`

Comment: I tried your code with some simple structs ; one with an optional and one without and the function takes an array of the first and returns a compactmap containing the second. I got no errors in either playgrounds nor Xcode 15

Comment: I also tried with a string and and a url property as output. Again,  no errors.  Can you create a [mcve]?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turns out Swift is just failing to infer the types correctly: simply annotating the `compactMap()` closure with the implied return type solves the issue:

```swift
    private func createSecondaryAttachments(
        _ attachments: [RegisteredMediaAttachment]
    ) -> [BasicAttachmentInput] {
        return attachments.compactMap { (attachment: RegisteredMediaAttachment) -> BasicAttachmentInput?
            // Note the explicit return type signature of the closure above ^
            guard let name = URL(string: $0.registration.uploadUrl) else {
                return nil
            }

            return BasicAttachmentInput(
                name: name,
                contentType: $0.attachment.type.mime(),
                sizeBytes: $0.attachment.data.count,
                mediaId: $0.registration.media.id
            )
        }
    }
```